# sending information through events in meteor

Tags: meteor

Ok so I'm working with meteor! Woo hoo I love it so far, but I've actually run into an architecture problem (or maybe its super simple and i just dont know it yet).

I have a list of names that belong to a user. And a delete button that is aligned next to the name

name - x
name - x
name - x

and I want a functionality to click the 'x', and then proceed to clearing the name from the database using the meteor event handler. I'm finding trouble thinking about how I'm going to pass the name along with the click to proceed to delete it from the database.

I can't use a unique id in the template to call a document.getElementById() (unless I came up with an integer system that followed the database.)

Does anyone have a good thought on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete working example:

### html

```html
<body>
  {{> userEdit}}
</body>

<template name="nameChoice">
  <p>
    <span>{{name}}</span>
    <a href="#" class="remove"> x</a>
  </p>
</template>

<template name="userEdit">
  {{#each nameChoices}}
    {{> nameChoice name=this}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

### js

```js
Users = new Meteor.Collection(null);

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    Users.insert({nameChoices: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']});
  });

  Template.userEdit.nameChoices = function () {
    return Users.findOne() && Users.findOne().nameChoices;
  };

  Template.nameChoice.events({
    'click .remove': function () {
      _id = Users.findOne()._id;
      Users.update(_id, {$pull: {'nameChoices': this.name}});
    }
  });
}
```

This actually does a bunch of stuff you wouldn't do in a real application (defined a client-only `Users` collection, assumes there is only one user, etc). But the main takeaway is that you can use the data context in each `nameChoice` template to respond to the remove event. This approach can nearly always replace the need for coming up with your own artificial id system. Feel free to ask questions if any of this is unclear.

Comment: It makes sense to me. I am out for the weekend but will try to implement it on Monday. Then I'll accept your answer!

Comment: Hey David, I got the data I needed to the server. Thanks a lot.